# Vue instance not mounting on instantiation

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I am using `vue-loader` in webpack and have a `vue-dialog.vue` file with `<script>`, `<style>` and `<template>`.

When I do `import dialog from './vue-dialog.vue` inside another file and call `new Vue(dialog)` I get a instance. But if I call `.$mount()` on it (to mount it off DOM) I get a error:

```
 [Vue warn]: Failed to mount component: template or render function not defined.
```

When I do `console.log(dialog.render)` I se the function there, when I do `console.log(instance.render)` its `undefined`.

If I instanciate it without calling `.$mount()` the instance has no `.$el` property, its `undefined`...

What am I missing? how else can I import a `.vue` file to another and call `new Vue()` to instanciate it and then mount it so I have a `.$el` element from the instance?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think `new Vue(dialog)` is a right way to instantiate a vue instance, instead you can use [`Vue.extend`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-extend) for instantiating.

```
import dialog from './dialog.vue';
// generate a constructor
const dialogCtor = Vue.extend(dialog);
// generate a new instance based on the constructor
const vm = new dialogCtor();
// then mount it
vm.$mount('#wherever');
```

Comment: Didn't work. Tried `const Dialog = Vue.extend(dialog);
const instance = new Dialog();
instance.$mount();` and got again: `[Vue warn]: Failed to mount component: template or render function not defined.` (thanks anyway for checking this out)

Comment: umm... that's strange. I instantiate in this way quite frequently, would you please show what your `dialog.vue` looks like?